# Spring security and ExceptionHandler: permitAll path exception always return 401 on Tomcat server

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with my Spring Boot application. I used Spring Security for authentication and ControllerAdvice annotation with @ExceptionHandler for exception handling. When I call a token protected api all goes well but when I try it on a path always authorized (like sign up or password reset) here comes the problem. If the response is 200 all is ok but when an exception is raised, and I can see the exception on the tomcat log, the response is always a 401 unauthorized, even if the the @ExceptionHandler should return a 403.

And the most weird thing about this behaviour is that it happens only on my online tomcat server and not when I run it on my local machine with tomcat started using gradle.

this is the configure function in spring security

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable() // We don't need CSRF for JWT based authentication
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Login end-point
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Token refresh end-point
            .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Sign up end-point
            .antMatchers(PHONE_PREFIXES_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Get international prefixes
            .antMatchers(ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Account activation end-point
            .antMatchers(PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Password reset email send
            .antMatchers(PASSWORD_RESET_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Password reset
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated() // Protected API End-points
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

this is the exception handled in the ControllerAdvice

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason="User already registered")
@ExceptionHandler(UserAlreadyRegisteredException.class)
public void handleUserAlreadyRegisteredException(UserAlreadyRegisteredException exception){}
```

This exception should be thrown when and user is already registered but instead it fires a 401.
Of course if I set in the request header the Authorization header it works.

Have someone just experienced this problem ? Could it be related to the Tomcat configuration ?

Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT**

This is the UserAlreadyRegisteredException class

```
public class UserAlreadyRegisteredException extends Exception {  
   public UserAlreadyRegisteredException(String email){ 
    super("User with email "+email+" already present");    
   } 
}
```

The path with the error is FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT which is defined in WebSecurityConfig

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 public static final String JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM = "Authorization";
 public static final String FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/login";
 public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/**";
 public static final String TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/token";
 public static final String FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/signup";
 public static final String PHONE_PREFIXES_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/phoneprefixes";
 public static final String ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/*/activate/*";
 public static final String PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/resetpassword";
 public static final String PASSWORD_RESET_ENTRY_POINT = UtilsProperties.API_PATH + "/auth/*/resetpassword/*";

@Autowired private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
@Autowired private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
@Autowired private AjaxAuthenticationProvider ajaxAuthenticationProvider;
@Autowired private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor;

@Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Bean
protected AjaxLoginProcessingFilter buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    AjaxLoginProcessingFilter filter = new AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT, successHandler, failureHandler, objectMapper);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
protected JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    List<String> pathsToSkip = Arrays.asList(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT, FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT, FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT, PHONE_PREFIXES_ENTRY_POINT, ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_ENTRY_POINT, PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_ENTRY_POINT, PASSWORD_RESET_ENTRY_POINT);
    SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT);
    JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter 
        = new JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(failureHandler, tokenExtractor, matcher);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}
 @Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
  return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }

 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
  auth.authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);
  auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
 }

 @Bean
 protected BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //the configure function added before
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I still cannot find a solution but I found out that the problem is the ControllerAdvice with the @ExceptionHandler.
In fact if, instead of throwing the exception, I normally return to the controller and I return a ResponseBody with the error all goes well.

Here the code in the controller

```
//register a new user
@RequestMapping(
        value = UtilsProperties.API_PATH+"/auth/signup",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity createUser( @RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String language, @RequestBody UserDto userDto ) throws SQLException, MessageNotFoundException, UserAlreadyRegisteredException, PermissionNotFoundException, UserNotFoundException, GroupNotFoundException, PermissionAlreadyInGroupException, InvalidEmailException, MailNotSentException, MissingParametersException, PhonePrefixNotFoundException, InvalidPasswordException, TelephoneAlreadyPresentException {
    User user = dtoConvertionService.convertUserToEntity(userDto);
    User savedUser = userService.create(user, language);
    if(savedUser.getIdUser().equals(-3L)) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .build();
    }
    EmailUtils.sendActivationMail(language, user);
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .body(dtoConvertionService.convertUserToDto(savedUser));
}
```

This is the whole controller advice. Every custom exception is declared in a separate file like UserAlreadyRegisteredException.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {


//AUTH
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Email not found")
@ExceptionHandler(EmailNotFoundException.class)
public void handleEmailNotFoundException(EmailNotFoundException exception){}

@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, reason="User not active")
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotActiveException.class)
public void handleUserNotActiveException(UserNotActiveException exception){}

//USERS
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="User not found")
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
public void handleUserNotFoundException(UserNotFoundException exception){}

@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason="User already registered")
@ExceptionHandler(UserAlreadyRegisteredException.class)
public void handleUserAlreadyRegisteredException(UserAlreadyRegisteredException exception){}

//more exceptions that don't need to be written

}
```

So the problem must be the fact that spring security filter run before the exceptionhandler. Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Comment: So when request to sigh up/password reset, you expect to return 403 when throws a UserAlreadRegiteredException? What's the real exception in backends when gets 401? and what does that mean 'Of course if I set in the request header the Authorization header it works.', does that mean you get 401 when you request the url without Authorization Header and expect to get 403 ?

Comment: @chaoluo The exception in the backend it's a UserAlreadyRegisterException (403). I can see it in the console. But then somehow a 401 is fired. Loggin the backend I found out that the function onAuthenticationFailure of my AuthenticationFailureHandler is called. That function shouldn't be called because the path shouldn't be under auth control. With the sentence about the authorization header I mean what you said. The authorization header shouldn't be needed. Anyway if I don't set it I can get 200 responses but not any other. 

And this doesn't happen on my local machine like I said before.

Comment: What's the request path when you get 401 that you expect to get 403?

Comment: @chaoluo It's FORM_BASED_REGISTRATION_ENTRY_POINT. If you want the request made to the server here it is: POST callmedevelop.cloudapp.net:8080/callme-0.1/auth/signup .
And this is an example of the json: { "name": "David", "surname": "Rainò", "email": "d.raino@hastega.it", "password": "Password1", "telephone": "3281457841", "prefixId": 1 } 
That email is already in the db so it should return a 403. Like I said that exception is thrown in the backend anyway

Comment: What's value of `UtilsProperties.API_PATH` on server ? How to change and get it when you deploy to server?

Comment: @chaoluo public static final String API_PATH = ""; This is only a variable that I use in case I'd like to change the base path of every request. In this moment it is an empty string as you can see. Anyway I don't think it's important in this case.

Comment: @chaoluo I found more details. See EDIT 2

Comment: Could please post you exception handler in SpringMVC config?

Comment: Did you override the default exception handler ?

Comment: @chaoluo No I didn't override it. Anyway I added in the edit class with the ControllerAdvice annotation. I don't have a springMVC config because I'm using Spring Boot. All I have is that class ExceptionHandlingController  and the exceptions that are declared in their own file like UserAlreadyRegisteredException.

Comment: that's too weird, Can you find what's real exception when you get 401 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130958/discussion-between-david-raino-and-chaoluo).

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: I haven't found anything usefull yet